# Javascript color slider

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am trying to implement a color picker like the one shown in the image below,[image: color picker]

in the first one, you can select a color and in the second one, you can select the range for that color anywhere between white and black.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: first create the color picker, then create the slider for the color picker.

Comment: You need to at least try, this is not a code writing service

Comment: I am done with creating the color picker, but i have no idea on how to create the slider for a particular color.

Comment: yes, but clearly there are lots of resources to help you in doing that. unless you have a specific question or problem, stack overflow is not the place for this question - see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was too big for comment.
Maybe something like this can help:
[`virtuosoft`](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/jquery-colorpickersliders/)
[`jscolor`](http://jscolor.com/examples/)
[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/66JJf/1/)
[`daviddurman`](http://www.daviddurman.com/flexi-color-picker/)